# Numbers arranged in a circle are painted blue or red. Prove that the sum of the red numbers is 0.

Tags: combinatorics

Numbers are arranged around a circle and are painted either blue or red. Every red number is equal to the sum of its two neighbors (left and right) and every blue number is equal to half the sum of its two neighbors (left and right). Prove that the sum of the red numbers is equal to $0$.

It's easy to prove that all numbers can't be red if they're not all $0$ and that if all numbers are blue they must all be equal, but I'm having difficulty going from here. I can't even find an example that fits our criteria. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming the sum is zero if there are no red numbers?

Comment: Why can't they all be blue?  True, they'd all be the same but what's wrong with that?

Comment: Oops, you're right, I assumed that if they're all blue they'd all be $0$ and for some reason thought that wouldn't work for us. Apologies.

Comment: I suspect you have to add up all the numbers round the circle and compare this to the sum of their left neighbours and the sum of their right neighbours.  So the total might be $S_r+S_b$ equal to $S_{left-r}+S_{left-b}=S_{right-r}+S_{right-b}$

Comment: And they can all be red as well (though in this case they must all be $0$).  But, again, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I've went ahead and corrected the post. (pretty sure for both cases only solution is $0$, that is all numbers must be $0$)

Comment: With all-blue, each can be $8$ or any other constant, but that leaves the non-existent reds adding up to $0$

Comment: Please read the comments, don't just guess blindly.  If the numbers are all the same they can all be blue.  Just try it.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Comment: The problem was on my school's selection competition a few years ago, I'm not sure of the exact source, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subtract from each number half the sum of its neighbors  (left and right) .  This will make blue numbers equal to zero and red numbers half their initial value. The total sum on the other hand will also become zero, as the value of each number is subtracted exactly once (half from its left neighbor and half from its right). So we have zero plus half the sum of red numbers is equal to zero. Therefore the sum of red numbers is zero.